# WPF - Drag and Drop ListBox Item to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, treeview

I am currently developing an application, using WPF, for my work to make some processing fast for staff. Basically, I have two parts of the screen. The left side has a list of Documents and the right side has a File structure. What I am trying to do is allow the user to drag and drop the document onto a folder so that the program can do the hard yards of moving the document. (This file system is a Document Management System that requires a bit of effort to move a document from one folder to another).

I am struggling with the Drag and Drop part. I have tried tutorials and even other posts on stackoverflow, however none of them are working the way that they should. There are even some methods that don't exist at times. So I am hoping that maybe someone would have done something recently that could even put me on the right track.

Below is my ListBox.

```
<ListBox Name="documentList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Extended" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Here is my TreeView

```
<TreeView x:Name="targetTreeView" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeView_Expanded" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>`
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are many tutorials which is complete and should work, such as codeproject [1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF) [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43702/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF-Part-II) [3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55168/Drag-and-Drop-Feature-in-WPF-TreeView-Control)

Comment: @LeiYang, Thanks for these. I had already seen the first 2, they were not helpful. The 3rd one was new to me, but didn't give me any insight on how to make my ListBoxItem's draggable. It did give me some insight on how to make the tree droppable, but I haven't gotten that far yet. :)